# Why does Nashorn's optimistic typing produce unpredictable results?

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I've been experimenting with Nashorn and got some strange results regarding the return types of `eval()`.

```
// calculator.js
var add = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

And the following Java code:

```
// CalculatorTest.java
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import javax.script.*
import org.junit.*
import jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngineFactory;

public class CalculatorTest {

    ScriptEngine nashorn;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws ScriptException {
        NashornScriptEngineFactory factory = new NashornScriptEngineFactory();
        nashorn = factory.getScriptEngine("–optimistic-types=true");
        nashorn.eval(new InputStreamReader(
                getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("calculator.js")));
    }

    @Test
    public void addViaInvokeFuntion() throws Exception {
        Object result = ((Invocable) nashorn).invokeFunction("add", 2, 3);
        Assert.assertEquals(5.0, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void addViaSimple() throws Exception {
        Object result = nashorn.eval("2+3");
        Assert.assertEquals(5, result);
    }

    @Test
    public void addViaMoreComplexEval() throws Exception {
        Object result = nashorn.eval(
                "var anotherAdd = function(a, b) {\n" +
                "    return a + b;\n" +
                "};\n" +
                "anotherAdd(2, 3);");
        Assert.assertEquals(5L, result);
    }
}
```

Why do these tests succeed in exactly this way?

Is there any way to "predict" the Nashorn return types?

Shouldn't the optimistic typing do exactly that?

Comment: I second this question as I stumbled upon this together with Michael.
To be more precisely: Why is an `Integer` returned, if the operation or function is called directly with `eval()` and why is an `Double` returned, if the function is called from an external js file?  
I'm fully aware, that `Number` should be used and that in JS, everything is a float kind. But beside of this, why is one time `Integer` returned and the other way a `Double`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see here is because of the way Nashorn creates specialized versions of functions based on input type of their parameters (and not optimistic typing per se). When you invoke `add` through `Invocable` interface you end up invoking the specialization `add(Object, Object)` and not `add(int, int)`. If the parameter types are objects, then there's no optimism to leverage; you get the following bytecode:

`public static add(Object;Object;Object;)Object;
    aload 1
    aload 2
    invokestatic ScriptRuntime.ADD(Object;Object;)Object;
    areturn`

(You can inspect these yourself if you add `--print-code` to the engine command line arguments; another helpful one is `--log=recompile` which'll print the type specializations of functions that have been generated.)

So it has nothing to do with `add` being defined in `calculator.js` but rather the fact that your call site – `Invocable.invokeFunction` is typed as taking all-object parameters.

`ScriptRuntime.ADD(Object, Object)` doesn't try to be too smart and narrow the type of its result; it's the generic-case slow-path `+` operator implementation that is used when there's no static information about parameter types, and it has to be prepared to deal with JavaScripts's weird cases such as `"2" + []` etc. Its code could certainly contain special optimization cases such as "if the result of the operation fits in an `Integer` return one", but we decided the additional complexity there ain't worth the hassle as you have lost static type information on input anyway. Hence, you'll get back a double for all numeric addition when the static type of the parameters is `Object`.

If on the other hand you'd execute `nashorn.eval("add(2, 3)")` then it would invoke the `add(int, int)` specialization, which is optimistic and you indeed end up with return value being integer 5.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @Attila, this really helped a lot to understand the differences! :-)

Answer (score 1):

The Java type used to represent a JS value in an *implementation* aspect (it is not part of ECMAScript spec. So long as typeof says "number" and arithmetic operations work as expected, any Java/JVM type should be fine). Using Java "int" to ECMAScript number value is an optimization. That optimization can not be done always. Only safe type inference can be done. Java side should expect any Number value to be returned for ECMAScript "number" value. These tests have to written to use java.lang.Number type. You can call "intValue", "doubleValue" methods on the return value (after casting returned Object as java.lang.Number) and assert the expected value.

Comment: Yes, as I already commented on the question, I know this. Actually I want to know, why it is `Integer` when evaluated directly with `eval(..)`, but `Double` when an external file with the _same_ function is loaded and executed/evaluated...